# Setting value of a form field in Django

Tags: django

I'm attempting to modify a field after the user has submitted the form. I've found several pieces of code online, but none seem to work. Below is my attempt in views.py. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
def newlisting(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ListingsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.cleaned_data['condition'] = 1   #form.condition = 1 also fails
            form.save()
            return redirect('/listings/')
        else:
            form = ListingsForm()
            return render(request, 'newlisting/newlisting.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like:

```
def newlisting(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ListingsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.condition = 1
            obj.save()
            return redirect('/listings/')
    else:
        form = ListingsForm()
    return render(request, 'newlisting/newlisting.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Perfect. Can you explain what `form = form.save(commit=False)` does please

Comment: @JShell This save() method accepts an optional commit keyword argument, which accepts either True or False. If you call save() with commit=False, then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the database. This is useful if you want to do custom processing on the object before saving it. for more details check this -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: Slightly misleading to call the result of `form.save()` "form" - it's not, it's the object. Better to do `obj = form.save(commit=False); obj.condition = 1; obj.save()`.

Comment: @JShell if my answer worked for you..please accept it.